# fetch() receive 200 but browser failed to load response data

Tags: reactjs

In a React app I've used fetch like this:

```js
fetch()
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => console.log(res)) // this print "undefined"
   .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

And response is 200 ok. But I cant see the content in the browser. The 200 is given by a Symfony controller like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class MoveController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/move', name: 'app_move')]
    public function index(): Response {
        
        // ... some content here ...
        // ... some content here ...
        
        return $this->json([
            'score' => 42,
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

Code is not working and whenever I click on the button I see current log in console:

```js
throw `Server error: [${resp.status}] [${resp.statusText}] [${resp.url}]`;
```

But see: the content of resp is nothing.

[image: what happen whenever I click on the button]

The full code is here

```js
       <button onClick={async () => {
            
            const response = await fetch('https://localhost:8000/move', {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                cache: 'no-cache',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                redirect: 'follow',
                referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'game_id': Math.random(),
                    'dices': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'category': '5',
                }),
            })
                .then((resp) => {
                    if (!resp.ok) {
                        console.log(resp)
                        throw `Server error: [${resp.status}] [${resp.statusText}] [${resp.url}]`;
                    }
                    return resp.json();
                })
                .then((json) => console.log(json))
                .catch(err => console.error(err))

                console.log(response)

        }}>send to server</button>
```

Why network return 200?

[image: server returns 200]

But I cant see the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `mode: 'no-cors'`. CORs doesn't just go away with this (despite the promising and slightly misleading name), you'll just get a response you can't read from for security reasons. Even though it's `200` in the network pane, as far as the JS is concerned its status code `0` and its body can not be seen. You need to remove `mode: 'no-cors'` and ensure CORS is correctly configured on your server.

`no-cors` is for some weird edge cases around loading scripts/images from servers that don't support CORs where the browser handles the contents natively without your code needing to inspect the response. You can't use it for communicating with your API.

Essentially: There is no escaping configuring your server to properly issue the relevant CORS headers.

Comment: 127.0.0.1/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:8000/move' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: Indeed. You will now need to setup CORS on your server. Google around it for your server technology. There is no avoiding it.

Comment: <?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTION') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
    die;
}

Comment: For whatever reason, your CORS headers are misconfigured or possibly not surfacing. Check response headers to ensure they are indeed there in the response. You might consider: https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle to do the heavy lifting. Generally you do this at the framework level.

Comment: ok, ... The problem is that I was using `symfony serve`. When you told me about nelmio I removed `symfony serve` and added an apache and an .htaccess file. NOW the content is available and it works. For some reason headers was working very bad with symfony server. I think.

Comment: Cool yeh that works. Doesn't matter so much what its served from -- the app itself, the web server, whatever.