# CORS policy issue in React and fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch

Im trying to fetch data from external api using fetch in react typescript component and having the error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.airtable.com/{my_data_base}' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header
field authentication is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
preflight response.
```

My React tsx component is:

```
import { FC, useEffect } from 'react';

const Collection: FC = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://api.airtable.com/v0/my_data_base', {
            headers: {
                mode: 'no-cors',
                Authentication: 'Bearer my_token',
            },
        })
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
    }, []);

    return <div>Collection Page Component</div>;
};

export default Collection
```

The same logic works fine with other apis, that don't require authorisation, like for example https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

Any idea how to fix it?
I've tried even the most stupid solution which is browser extensions but non of them worked.

Comment: I answered a question that is exactly this just now over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485528/fetch-receive-200-but-browser-failed-to-load-response-data/76485610?noredirect=1#comment134861246_76485610.

Comment: However if airtable does not have the CORS headers, then possibly your account is misconfigured. I would contact airtable. Moreover, its usually better to do the airtable cllas on the server and then return the results over your own API, Because otherwise any end user could just steal your auth token and use it at will which is insecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `mode` property is not part of the `headers` object but it belongs to the entier options object just like `herders`, second you don't need it. 
Also the property for passing tokens is `Authorization` not `Authentication`.

Comment: Correct, mode is not headers property - my bad.

Comment: @dariusz try it with `Authorization`

Comment: Authorization works!  Thanks! Postman habit. For axios I checked documentation instead of typing from my head :)